# Book identification: guys lives on island, expelled, foreign sorcerers invade

Tags: story-identification

There was this book about a guy living on an island, he got expelled then the city was invaded by foreigners who knew magic. There was a shopkeeper who was some sort of seriously dangerous / killer monster not really specified of what sort yet.

Comment: Do you remember when you read it?

Comment: Not too long ago. The story must be contemporary.

Comment: Does the idea of a glass dagger magically fixed in a guy's heart ring a bell?

Comment: Nope. But the question can be closed (should I put in a self answer?) because I found it: A Crucible of Souls by Mitchell Hogan. However, a glass dagger magically fixed in a guy's heart sounds an interesting book, what is that :) ?

Comment: Yes, you can add an answer yourself, then wait a couple of days and mark it accepted.

Comment: @chx - "What Good Is A Glass Dagger?" (short story) by Larry Niven. It was tantalizingly similar. A young werewolf is sent by Atlantis to steal the Warlock's Wheel, a spell which destroys magic. He fails, and cannot return to Atlantis. 20 years later he is a rug merchant when he meets the Warlock again. His city is frequently buying "trolls" as slaves,which are actually reanimated, magically-disguised corpses, which will at some point kill everybody in the city. Ultimately the rug merchant kills the necromancer by attacking as a werewolf. Can be found in Isaac Asimov's "Wizards"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Crucible of Souls by Mitchell Hogan.

Comment: Why does that match the question?